# PropertiesLauncher unable to jar files in Uberjar when using Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

We seem to be having an issue while using propertiesLauncher (layout as ZIP). When we run the jar with or without using -Dloader.path

```
java   -jar  myuberjar.jar
```

We keep getting an error saying that it is not able to find jar file that is present in myuberjar.jar

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File [/Users/myuser/myuberjar.jar!/lib/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.5.4.jar] referenced by given URL [file:/Users/myuser/myuberjar.jar!/lib/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.5.4.jar] does not exist
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.internal.StandardArchiveDescriptorFactory.buildArchiveDescriptor(StandardArchiveDescriptorFactory.java:73)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.internal.JarProtocolArchiveDescriptor.<init>(JarProtocolArchiveDescriptor.java:71)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.internal.StandardArchiveDescriptorFactory.buildArchiveDescriptor(StandardArchiveDescriptorFactory.java:55)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.internal.StandardArchiveDescriptorFactory.buildArchiveDescriptor(StandardArchiveDescriptorFactory.java:48)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.scan.spi.AbstractScannerImpl.buildArchiveDescriptor(AbstractScannerImpl.java:95)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.scan.spi.AbstractScannerImpl.scan(AbstractScannerImpl.java:70)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.scan(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:725)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:221)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:188)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider$1.<init>(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:49)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:49)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
```

Not sure what we are missing.

SpringBoot - 1.2.4.RELEASE
JDK1.8
PropertiesLauncher

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
               <layout>ZIP</layout>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

When i extract the uberjar , i can see all the jars in the lib folder. Bellow are the contents of the manifest file

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: AppService
Implementation-Version: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: avinash
Start-Class: com.company.app.AppServiceApplication
Implementation-Vendor-Id: com.company.services.app
Spring-Boot-Version: 1.2.4.RELEASE
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.2.1
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_25
Implementation-Vendor: Pivotal Software, Inc.
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with Spring Boot properties launcher, but more with Hibernate jars as described in the bug below.

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4161